# Extract div tags with specific class using PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, dom

Does any one know how to extract only div tags with particular class,in PHP?

```
<div class="abc">
</div>
<div class="def">
</div>
<div class="xyz">
</div>
```

I need div only with class="abc".
How can I implement that?

Comment: possibly asking for [Best methods to parse HTML in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php), but currently NARQ.

Comment: Try using DOM, http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is: [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)

```
<?php
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHtmlFile('thepage.html');
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );
$nodelist = $xpath->query( "//*[contains(@class, 'abc')]" );
foreach ($nodelist as $n){
  echo $n->nodeValue."\n";
}
?>
```

**[updated]**

Added new xpath query. 
give that a try.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But its giving not giving me the results that I need.
<br>
DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 0 )

Comment: is the file located on the same server? or a remote file?