# Remove specific tags from a php string

Tags: php, html-parsing

I wonder if there is any way to remove a specific tags from a php string?

I have knowledge of several features that make it, for example `strip_tags`, but what I really want is to remove tags containing the class attribute or any, I give an example below:

`$string = '<p>Test paragraph.<p class="inner">Here is some inner text</p></p>';`

How I can remove only the tag containing the class attribute 'inner'?

If anyone can tell me a way to do this, I'd be grateful.

Comment: You'll need to parse the HTML yourself.

Comment: Use a DOM parser to parse your HTML, then modify the DOM and recreate the HTML from the DOM.  Look at the [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) page.  This is not a problem you want to solve with regular expressions.

Comment: I've asked a similar doubt.[This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154595/extract-div-tags-with-specific-class-using-php) has the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no function to do that, and to avoid using a horrible regular expression the best way would be to load it into a `DOMDocument` class and iterate over the tags in the string. You can then selectively remove tags depending on the class attribute and then write it back out to a string.

See http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php for the documentation.

Comment: @evolquez: No need for iteration. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple with XPath:

```
<?php

$string = '<p>Test paragraph.<p class="inner">Here is some inner text</p></p>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadXML($string);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$inners = $xpath->query('//p[@class="inner"]'); //Select all p.inner in the document

foreach ($inners as $element) {
    $element->parentNode->removeChild($element); //Remove 'em
}

var_dump($dom->saveHTML($dom));
```